How to update uiState in ViewModel when an event occurs?
I'm just learning how to manage UI States. In the following example I'm using combine() for 2 of my use cases and they are collected when the app starts. But what if I want to collect a 3rd different use case when the user clicks a button, for example. How could I update the state in this case. Should I use a separate and different StateFlow? Thanks in advance!
val uiState: StateFlow<NewsUiState> =
        combine(
            getAllTopNewsUseCase(), 
            getNewsByKeywordUseCase(_keywordSearch.value)
        ) { latestNews, newsByKeyword ->
            when {
                latestNews.isNullOrEmpty() -> NewsUiState.Success(newsByKeyword = newsByKeyword)
                newsByKeyword.isNullOrEmpty() -> NewsUiState.Success(latestNews = latestNews)
                else -> NewsUiState.Success(latestNews, newsByKeyword)
            }

        }.catch {
            NewsUiState.Error(it)
        }.stateIn(
            scope = viewModelScope,
            started = SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000),
            initialValue = NewsUiState.Loading
        )

This is the sealed interface I defined to hold the state:
sealed interface NewsUiState {
    object Loading: NewsUiState
    data class Success(
        val latestNews: List<NewsItem>? = null,
        val newsByKeyword: List<NewsItem>? = null
    ): NewsUiState
    data class Error(val throwable: Throwable): NewsUiState

}

And, if it's useful this is how I produce state from my Screen:
val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current.lifecycle
    val uiState by produceState<NewsUiState>(
        initialValue = NewsUiState.Loading,
        key1 = lifecycle,
        key2 = newsViewModel,
    ) {
        lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle(state = Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
            newsViewModel.uiState.collect { value = it }
        }
    }

    when(uiState) {
        is NewsUiState.Error -> TODO()
        NewsUiState.Loading -> TODO()
        is NewsUiState.Success -> TODO()
    }


You don’t collect events. Events like a button click should call a function in the ViewModel. That function will modify some relevant state that you are observing in your Composables. Whether it modifies the state you already show above, or if you need to create another flow to represent something else that will appear on screen, that depends on what you want the button to do.

As Tenfour04 said, you should update a state that is observing using a function. Here's a good link to check. If you're working with a ViewModel, you should add an observable there and modify that observable using a function.
https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/state-saving
